# react-native-element-timer useRef object is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-elements

I am using the react-native-element-timer (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-element-timer) and have a problem with the useRef hook.

The reference of timerRef is set with the rendering of the "Timer" element, but I want the timer to directly start when the function "Stopwatch" is called and **not** with onButtonClick. So i need to reference that Timer before it is rendered.

When I try it like this (see below), then an error occurs "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'timerRef.current.start')".

```
export default function Stopwatch(item, process) {
    import React, { useRef } from 'react';
    import { Timer } from 'react-native-element-timer';


    const timerRef = useRef(null);

    //timerRef.current.start(); <--- this should be called with function Stopwatch

    return (
        <View >
            <Timer
                ref={timerRef}

                onTimes={e => { }}
                onEnd={e => { }}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

################

Update:

With

```
const timerRef = useRef(new Date)
```

I get another error:

```
TypeError: timerRef.current.start is not a function. (In 'timerRef.current.start()', 'timerRef.current.start' is undefined)
```

Comment: const timerRef = useRef(new Date)

Comment: thanks for your response. unfortunately almost the same error: 
TypeError: timerRef.current.start is not a function. (In 'timerRef.current.start()', 'timerRef.current.start' is undefined)

Comment: need to reference that <Timer> before it is rendered. is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are calling `timerRef.current.start();` in components body (and we don't know when this line code will be called by React, maybe before the ref is resolved).

Much better use `useEffect` hook:

```
const timerRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
   if(timerRef.current) timerRef.current.start();
}, [])
```

In this way you are sure that `timerRef.current` is not undefined

Comment: Happy to help you. Have a nice coding =)

Answer (score 0):

call in the new button `timerRef.current.start()`

```
                <Button
                    style={styles.button}
                    title={'Start'}
                    onPress={() => {
                        timerRef.current.start();
                    }}
                />
```